# Prove that the following function $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere if $\sum_q qg(q) < \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

We define a function for $0\leq x \leq 1$ 
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
g(q),  & \text{if $x=\frac{p}{q}\in \mathbb{Q}$ with $gcd(p,q)=1$}, \\
0, & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$

I want to prove that this function is differentiable almost everywhere if $\sum_q qg(q) < \infty.$

$$g(q) = q^{-\alpha} ~~ for ~~\alpha>2$$

Can someone give me a hint for this exercise?

Comment: what is $g(q)?$

Comment: As written above, I have no idea - it's not specified. Just the property with the sum ist known.

Comment: Where is the problem from?

Comment: It is an exercise from my measure theory course. I don't know where my professor took ist from.

Comment: I got just got a reply from my professor - I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Let $r > 0$. The set $S$ of real numbers $x$ such that there exists a real number $u$ at distance at most $r$ with $|f(x)-f(u)|>\epsilon|x-u|$ is the reunion of $\mathbb{Q}$ and of the $(u-\rho_u,u+\rho_u)$, $\rho_u$ being the minimum of $\frac{|f(u)|}{\epsilon}$ and $r$, for rational $u$.

In particular, the outer measure $\mu_{r,\epsilon}$ of $S$ is at most $2\sum_u{\rho_u}$.

By the assumption, we know that $\sum_u{|f(u)|} < \infty$, and thus we can use the (“discrete”) DCT to show that $\mu_{r,\epsilon}$ goes to zero as $r$ goes to $0$ for any $\epsilon$.

So we can find decreasing sequences going to $0$, $\epsilon_n,r_n$ such that $\sum_n{\mu_{r_n,\epsilon_n}} < \infty$.

From Borel-Cantelli it follows that if $S_n$ is the “$S$” from above associated with $r_n$ and $\epsilon_n$, almost every real number is in only finitely many $S_n$. But you can check that if $z$ is in only finitely many $S_n$, $f$ is differentiable at $z$.